# SVG stops animation when DOM is getting modified

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, svg

so I made an SVG loader. It runs perfectly while the request to the server is taking place, but when data comes and the DOM is getting filled my SVG stops, is this an issue with the browser itself or is it something im missing?

```
//Getting data from the server and start spinner
svgSpinner.open();
$.ajax({
url: "http://anyUrl",

}).done(function(data) {

  //create DOM elements and close spinner
  createElements(data);
  svgSpinner.close();
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Please could you provide a JSFiddle, or at least an example of yhe code you are using. Thank you

Comment: Well, if your createElements() is asyncronous this would be exactly the expected behaviour I should think.

Comment: The thing is, that I would expect to add the DOM elements and then close the spinner. While the createElements function is still going the spinner should spin.

Comment: Actually I just tested without any spinner close and it stops while adding a lot of elements into the DOM, and then continues to spin. I think it's just the browser can't handle all that.

Comment: Post your createElements(data); function.